# QHeaderView заголовки секций

Tags: qt, qt5

Создал `QTableWidget`, повешал на него свои `QHeaderView` и получилось так:

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Код:

```
TableViewer = new QTableWidget(1, 2, this);

QHeaderView * hHeader = new QHeaderView(Qt::Horizontal);
TableViewer->setHorizontalHeader(hHeader);

QHeaderView * vHeader = new QHeaderView(Qt::Vertical);
TableViewer->setVerticalHeader(vHeader);

TableViewer->show();
```

Далее читал доку на `QHeaderView` и `QAbstractItemView` и нигде не нашел как менять заголовки у секции(столбцов/строк), в моем случае необходимо в столбцах заменить 1 и 2 на свои надписи, как это сделать?
Ну или вообще спрятать хэдер, что бы в окне виджета отображались только ячейки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы поменять текст заголовка, вызывайте у модели метод `setHeaderData`.
Чтобы скрыть:

```
view->horizontalHeader()->hide();
view->verticalHeader()->hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
QListString Ls << "One" << "Two" << "Three";

TableViewer->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(Ls);
```